# Error while installing Atom Editor

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, atom-editor

I got this error while installing Atom on PopOs.

What is happening here?

```
sudo dpkg --install atom-amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 215577 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack atom-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking atom (1.41.0) over (1.41.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5) | libgconf2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
  Package libgconf2-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package atom (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the dependencies for the package. If they can be satisfied, you can do it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```